# Missing Content Importer and Content Processor in XNA Game Studio 4.0 on XP

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, windows-xp, installation, xna-4.0

I've downloaded and installed Visual C# 2010 Express and XNA Game Studio 4.0 on to my XP (32-bit) machine. I had to do this by downloading the files individually as the App Hub package wouldn't install when I tried that, something to do with the Windows Phone stuff.

Anyway, I'm having trouble with transparency on PNGs and I took the project in to work today, and found that by changing Content Importer and Processor (properties) transparency worked fine, this was on a Windows 7 machine.

However on my XP installation at home, the drop down menus for these two boxes are empty. I have tried complete uninstall and re-install but this didn't help. Is there anything else I can try?

I can run the code fine, just can't get transparency on my images.

I'm basically missing the drop-downs shown in the image on this page:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb199633(v=XNAGameStudio.40).aspx

**Interesting Addition: If i set the importer and processor at work, save the project, and bring it home, the settings show up and work. So it appears i'm purely missing the link between the drop down menus and the available settings.**

Comment: You might need to be more specific. Which files did you download individually? What did you change the Importer and Processor to? What problem are you having with transparency? (Screenshot?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I never found a solution to this whilst using XP. However now that I have upgraded to Windows 7 everything works as expected. I can only therefore assume that either there was something incorrect with my installations of the Net Framework, XNA Game Studio, or XP; or alternatively XNA Game Studio does not fully support XP.

Answer (score 0):

On the off chance that "downloading the files individually" means you've downloaded the wrong thing, [here is the **stand-alone installer** for XNA Game Studio 4.0](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=9AC86ECA-206F-4274-97F2-EF6C8B1F478F), which *will* run on Windows XP.

(The Windows Phone Developer Tools, on the other hand, will only install on Vista and above.)

Comment: I think this is the one I downloaded but I'll give it another try, cheers.

Comment: It appears that this is the same one I downloaded and installed.

Answer (score 0):

I was having problems with transparency in my PNGs as well. It may be the program you're using to create/convert the png files. I used irfanview and no longer have any problems.

Comment: It's not the PNGs because when I tried them at work, I had the options to use the Content Importer and Processor. The PNGs worked fine. This was one of my initial thoughts though.